# Not able to see images from android storage in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions, react-native-permissions

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

App.js

```
  const App = () => {

  const [uri, setUri] = useState("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_20200902-162017_Netflix.jpg")

    const requestPermission = async () => {
        await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
            title: 'Get Read External Storage Access',
            message: 'get read external storage access for detecting screenshots',
            buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
        );
    }

    const requestPermission2 = async () => {
        await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
            title: 'Get Read External Storage Access',
            message: 'get read external storage access for detecting screenshots',
            buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
        );
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        requestPermission()
        requestPermission2()

    },[])  

   return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
            source={{uri : `file://${uri}`}}
            style={{height:'100%', width:'100%'}}
        />

        </View>
   );
};
```

When I went into the app settings, I got permission

"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_20200902-162017_Netflix.jpg file is Actually exists.

Why can't I see anything

Comment: You are on an Android Q/10 device?

Comment: `..../DCIM/Screenshots` On most devices Screenshots go in `..../Pictures/Screenshots`

Comment: `......Netflix.jpg file is Actually exists.` How did you check? Need to check with some code in your app as different apss have different permissions and access possibilities.

Comment: as far as i know file:// is not a valid prefix for an image resource. Check out the docs on images for the different options of parameters you can pass to Image source property: https://reactnative.dev/docs/images.html

You might also want to have a look at the https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll package and check out their implementation.

Comment: @blackapps 
I checked the path with @react-native-community/cameraroll  getPhotos method and console.log(getPhotos result[0])
result is '...../DCIM/Screenshots'
My Android version is Q/10

Comment: @tijs
I use github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll
I use getPhotos method and there is no error... but getPhotos sample code in github link is not showing image.

Comment: On Android Q/10 you have no access to that externel storage location anymore unless you add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to application tag in manifest file.

Comment: @blackapps
I set android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" it works! thanks!!

Comment: You are glad now but for Android above Q you have to come up with something different.

Comment: @blackapps

Can you give me a related link for reference?

Comment: Just google for android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true".